# Add external JS script through code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, src

I'm trying to implement a map widget from 'Awesome Table' in the source code of an open-source CRM.

The piece of code I have to add is

```
 <div data-type="AwesomeTableView" data-viewID="-KLtnY5OHJPgnEOX1bKf"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://awesome-table.com/AwesomeTableInclude.js"></script>
```

I try to do it with jQuery like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var div = "<div data-type=\"AwesomeTableView\" data-viewID=\"-KLtnY5OHJPgnEOX1bKf\"></div>";
    var scr = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://awesome-table.com/AwesomeTableInclude.js\"></script>";
    $("body").append(div, scr);
});
```

But I got a problem : in the console the src appears like this:

> http://127.0.0.1/edsa-EspoCRM-4.1.6/api/v1/https://awesome-table.com/AwesomeTableInclude.js

See what's wrong...

Before I tried with javascript but I had an almost identical result (nothing appeared and the script didn't worked)

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "lacarte";
div.dataset.type = "AwesomeTableView";
div.dataset.viewid = "-KLtnY5OHJPgnEOX1bKf";
div.style.height = "200px";

var scr = document.createElement("script");
scr.type = "text/javascript";
scr.src = "https://awesome-table.com/AwesomeTableInclude.js";
var page = document.getElementById("content");
page.appendChild(div);
page.appendChild(scr);
```

If you have any idea?

Comment: Did you try `$.getScript` ot load and execute your JS script instead of appending it ? (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Comment: How can I use it in my situation ?

Comment: See the answer i posted.

Comment: What's the CRM you are using ?

Comment: As I can see, you tried to find some help on their forums to make your extension (http://forum.espocrm.com/forum/developer-help/22715-adding-content-to-a-new-tab). Did you try to include the JS files from `AwesomeTable` in your extensions' folder ? (eg. `client/custom/src/views/my-entity/`)

Comment: Yeah I tried to find some help but they are apparently busy :/ I'll try that

Comment: Do you know what I have to do after including my "WorldMap.js" in client/custom/src/views/WorldMap/ ? Do I have to change my src ?

Comment: Please post the code of your `view`.

Comment: Sorry, my "view" ?

Comment: In the forum page, `clientDefs` contains a `views` property in which you declare your view (if i understand well the post). In the example he gave, he declares a view naamed `list` with the path `views/my-entity/list`. So, i suppose you did the same for your extension.

Comment: This part was to explain how to delete all the buttons and the list of datas of the page. After modifying some code in list.js he said to me to look into I was able to do it. In the same file I try to adapt the widget code now...

Comment: But I possibly don't understand correctly what I'm supposed to do with those files :/

Comment: So, i don't know how to help you. It seems that espocrm is replacing the url when you include it.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the slashes in the script `src`, `type` and closing of the script `/`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var div = '<div data-type="AwesomeTableView" data-viewID="-KLtnY5OHJPgnEOX1bKf"></div>';
    var scr = '<script type="text\/javascript" src="https:\/\/awesome-table.com\/AwesomeTableInclude.js"><\/script>';
    $("body").append(div, scr);
});
```

Comment: Why escaping the slash of the closing tag and not those in the `src` attribute ?

Comment: Also escaping slashes is useless, it is not a special char like a backslash... (And you missed some other slashes in `src` and `type` attribbutes, if you want to be "correct")

Comment: Yeah, same result :/

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$.getScript` to load and execute scripts dynamically.

And if your script is a prerequisite for your `div`, you can use the `callback` executed when the script is loaded end executed, to append the div.

Here is the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getScript("https://awesome-table.com/AwesomeTableInclude.js", function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        var div = '<div data-type="AwesomeTableView" data-viewID="-KLtnY5OHJPgnEOX1bKf"></div>';
        $("body").append(div);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code adds the two elements exactly as shown.

```js
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id);}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
 var div = newEl('div');
 div.setAttribute('data-type', 'AwesomeTableView');
 div.setAttribute('data-viewID', '-KLtnY5OHJPgnEOX1bKf');

 var script = newEl('script');
 script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
 script.setAttribute('src', 'https://awesome-table.com/AwesomeTableInclude.js');

 document.body.appendChild(div);
 document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

The resulting source is: https://awesome-table.com/AwesomeTableInclude.js
As seen here:

```
<body>
<div data-type="AwesomeTableView" data-viewid="-KLtnY5OHJPgnEOX1bKf"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="https://awesome-table.com/AwesomeTableInclude.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I just tried and nothing appeared on my page :O but I don't get the error

Comment: ave you tried looking at the source of the js file? The very first thing it does is add an event listener for DOMContentLoaded. Therefore, if you're running code to add the script in the onload event like my code does, its being done too late. The script wont run since the event its waiting for has already happened..